# Change SPI slave select line timing

Tags: microcontroller, timing, spi, slave, nrf52

Is it possible to change the timing of SPI slave select line on a microcontroller? How is the timing of slave select line determined?
I am using SPI interface of nrf52DK microcontroller board. For 125kHz SPI clock, the slave select line has a low level of 165 us but the high level is quite long (appears for a long time before transitioning to next low level) and I want to change this. I want to reduce the length of high level on the slave select line. I checked this on an oscilloscope.

Comment: This totally depends on the microcontroller. Most I've used require you to drive the chip select line manually with a GPIO, so the timing is... whatever you want it to be. You need to include more information about what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you for your reply. I have too previously driven Chip Select lines manually while working with other microcontrollers, so the timing could be controlled based on when high and lows are given to the GPIO. But haven't seen that with most microcontroller boards having their own APIs.

Comment: A high level corresponds to the time between different transmission chunks.  So, it's also a factor of how much work is done in between transmissions to prepare the next chunk.  Therefore, there is no fixed or right amount of time.